# Prevent request via IP address of server

Tags: apache2, ip-address, mod-security

I'm pretty sure there's a way to prevent access to a website through the server IP address and to force the user to enter the domain name instead.

so that `http://156.56.75.87` should trigger a 403 and only access through `http://www.example.com` should  be authorized.

I think there was a modsecurity rule for that but I can't find it anywhere. Does someone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule to activate this block rule in mod_security can be found in: 
 `base_rules/modsecurity_crs_21_protocol_anomalies.conf`

That will block access to the website when accessed through the server IP-address.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an .htaccess option for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^10\.0\.11\.101$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

...to redirect and...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^10\.0\.11\.101$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

...to block.

Obviously, you will need to change the IP address and domain name to suit your needs. This should redirect any IP based reference to the domain name.

Comment: thanks for that but what I want is to reject the request. Here you are rewriting to the domain name.

Comment: @Sam Ooopppsss! My Bad!! I updated the answer and left the other option for others down the road.

Comment: ok that would work. My question was related to modsecurity though :) I found the answer somewhere else on SO. I'll post the answer below. Thanks for you help!

Comment: @Sam I do highly recommend using mod_security but also recommend where possible using HTTP filters and firewall rules to keep bad actors from the server if possible. Of course this is not always available for hosting. But if a firewall with these options are available, this is a powerful option too. Again, I do recommend mod_security for everyone where possible. One up-vote on the way!

Comment: You would need to change `REMOTE_ADDR` to `HTTP_HOST` in order to catch the situation when the website itself is accessed by the server's IP address. `REMOTE_ADDR` is the IP address of the client accessing the site.

Comment: @user82217 Noted and corrected with much gratitude. I took this from an old example and missed the change required somehow. Cheers Mate!!