# Deny access from the server's IP address and allow www.example.com using Apache configuration

Tags: apache2, configuration

I have the following configuration in my *apache2.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@Host-Wordpress-01
   DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress_example
   Servername www.example.com
   ServerAlias example.com
 </VirtualHost>
```

All I want is to change it so it's not accessible by an IP address anymore (i.e., the server's IP address) and only by `www.example.com`

What would I change?

Comment: Here is an example for your site assuming Apache (the first of the two): http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/68307/prevent-request-via-ip-address-of-server/68310#68310

Answer (score 2):

The solution would be the same as for [Block a random domain pointing at my dedicated IP](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72689/block-a-random-domain-pointing-at-my-dedicated-ip).   I posted an answer there with configuration and a script.

Basically, you need to create a default virtual host entry to handle the IP address and any other random addresses.   Then you can have your real site in a second virtual host directive that is specific to your site.